# Unable to set custom resolution on GNOME Wayland via boot parameters

Tags: gnome, grub2, wayland

I'm trying to push GNOME to 2560X1080 resolution on Wayland, but this resolution is not available on the "Displays" settings menu. I've read ([here](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/05/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-wayland-xorg/), [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1210275), and [here](https://superuser.com/a/1168914)) that one can add custom resolutions to wayland by editing boot parameters in their GRUB config like so:

**Attempt 1**

```bsh
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=2560x1080@60"
```

This should make the desired resolution available on the aforementined "Displays" menu for all connected monitors, but it didn't work for me. I tried specifying the target monitor, with no luck:

```bsh
$ for p in /sys/class/drm/*/status; do con=${p%/status}; echo -n "${con#*/card?-}: "; cat $p; done

DP-1: disconnected
DP-2: disconnected
eDP-1: connected
HDMI-A-1: connected
HDMI-A-2: disconnected
```

**Attempt 2**

```bsh
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=eDP-1:2560x1080@60"
```

**Attempt 3**

```bsh
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=HDMI-A-1:2560x1080@60"
```

Other info that might be relevant: I edited these boot parameters using Grub Customizer and I'm running the [linux-surface](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface) kernel on Ubuntu. The high resolution display is an external one, connected to a laptop.

Since none of my attempts worked, I'm back to Xorg which is working thanks to `xrandr`. However, I really do like the improved security and "smoothness" of Wayland, so I'd immensely appreciate any help regarding this issue. Thanks in advance :)